# Rails :Can't save audio file (paperclip)

Tags: ruby, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5

I can't save audio file, so can you tell me how to save about audio file .
I use gem paperclip !

log is 
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/1z/psyvq9q911b7hclx5xw03dk40000gn/T/4266fc074db087b967597da8e4d2d11020171116-3739-1bal5v0.mp3'
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename as333auda.mp3 (audio/mp3 from Headers, ["audio/mpeg"] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: video/mp4. See documentation to allow this combination.
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/1z/psyvq9q911b7hclx5xw03dk40000gn/T/4266fc074db087b967597da8e4d2d11020171116-3739-wh10af.mp3'
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename as333auda.mp3 (audio/mp3 from Headers, ["audio/mpeg"] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: video/mp4. See documentation to allow this combination.
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/listings/new
Completed 302 Found in 128ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)

show you model listing.rb

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :user
     has_many :photos
     has_many :likes
     has_many :customers
     has_many :reviews
     validates :listing_title, presence: true

    has_attached_file  :file,  :storage => :s3,
                               :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml"

   validates_attachment :file, content_type: { content_type: ['file/mp3'] }


 end
```

show you view new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @listing do |f| %>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12 select">
       <div class="form-group">
        <label>タイトル</label>
           <%= f.text_field :listing_title, autofocus: true, :placeholder => "タイトル", :class => 'form-control', required: "true" %>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <br>

     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 select">
       <div class="form-group">
        <label>ファイル</label>
          <%= f.file_field :file, :class => 'form-control' %>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <br>

     <div class="actions">
       <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-danger" %>
     </div>
<% end %>
```

Controller is nothing problem! I set params!
What should I need I success to save audio file?
Please tell me!

Comment: Isn't the mime type for MP3 files `audio/mpeg`? _I can't save_ is not very helpful. Is there an error message? A validation error? Is there a message in the log file. What happens if you try?

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited! Add problem content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
{ content_type: ['audio/mp3'] }
```

If this still doesn't work you can try this:

```
{ content_type: ['audio/mpeg', 'audio/x-mpeg', 'audio/mp3', 'audio/x-mp3', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/x-mpeg3', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/x-mpg', 'audio/x-mpegaudio'] }
```

Comment: Thank you for me!
I understand, and I  was solved by you! Thank you!!

Comment: @DaichiDaichi You're welcome :) I struggled with the same thing a while back.

Answer (score 0):

MP3 audio files has mime typed `"audio/mpeg"`

Change your content type to `"audio/mpeg"`

Comment: Thank you for me! 

validates_attachment :file, content_type: { content_type: [ "audio/mpeg" ] }
Is this right?

Comment: But I can't save!

Comment: Try to create Listing in `rails console` like `l = Listing.create file: File.new('/path/anymp3.mp3')` and show the output of `l.errors.full_messages`